# bootstrapping difference in sum in R

Tags: r, bootstrap

I would like to test the significance of difference in sum by bootstrapping.

Previously, I only used bootstrapping when testing the difference in means. For example, I used the following code based on Efron and Tibshirani (1993).

```
xt   <- var1 - mean(var1) + mean(var3)
yt   <- var2 - mean(var2) + mean(var3)

set.seed(123)
boot.t <- c(1:10000)
for (j in 1:10000){
   sample.x <- sample(xt,replace=TRUE)
   sample.y <- sample(yt,replace=TRUE)
boot.t[j] <- t.test(sample.x,sample.y)$statistic

}
```

I would like to ask any suggestion on how to test the difference in sum?Or is there a particular statistical test that I can use aside from bootstrapping.

Comment: You will need to explain why the difference in sum is not equal to the difference in mean multiplied by the original sample size